# How to deal with duplicates between different SE communities?

Tags: discussion

What if a certain question is asked on a specific SE community, but has a duplicate on a different SE community. Should it be possible for those questions to be linked to each other? Or how should they be dealt with? I think this happens specifically with the meta parts on SE, where people usually visit the meta page of the community they frequent most, instead of going to the general meta SE.

For example, I personally frequent the Anime & Manga SE and I just noticed [a question about downvoting](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/downvoting-shouldnt-people-comment-why-they-downvote), which is an obvious duplicate of [the same question on the general meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

How should this situation be dealt with best?